# opencv histogram comparison without color

Tags: opencv

I am using opencv's compareHist_Demo.cpp histogram comparison program to compare two images. It works great when two images are of the same color and same shape. The problem is if I want to compare two images of different color and same shape I cannot get a good result because of the lighting. What Opencv algorithm should I use if I only want to compare the shape of the two images? I tried to grayscale both images but there is still a color difference and the result does not seem to be good. Any hint is good. BTW the image is mostly textures not shape.

Comment: Try grayscale + white balance equalization. That is, stretch both histograms to have nonzero values at 0 and 255.

Comment: I tried that, but Histogram comparison only compares the pixel tonal count without checking the shape or the texture. I am looking into Gabor filter but it seems too complicated. Is there another algorithm I can try out? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You should look at feature based image matching (SIFT/SURF/etc.)

Comment: Hmm, I got the opencv_contrib built and compiled in the opencv/install path, but how do I incorporate it with Visual Studio 2012?